# class same signal connected to multiple instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

If I define a `disable_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()` outside of the custom button class, the behaviour I am looking for (all instance are disabled when clicked upon).

```
class CustomButton(QtWidgets.QToolButton):    
    def __init__(self, parent, disable_signal):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.disable_signal = disable_signal
        self.disable_signal.connect(self.disable)
        self.pressed.connect(self.buttonPressed)

    def buttonPressed(self):
        self.disable_signal.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def disable(self):
        print("received")
        self.setEnabled(False)
```

However, if I define the signal as a class attribute, each instance behave as if they each had their individual signal (pressing upon one, disable only that one):

```
class CustomButton(QtWidgets.QToolButton):
    disable_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.disable_signal.connect(self.disable)
        self.pressed.connect(self.buttonPressed)

    def buttonPressed(self):
        self.disable_signal.emit()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def disable(self):
        print("received")
        self.setEnabled(False)
```

I don't understand why the signal is not shared? I tried to use instead of `self.disable_signal.connect(self.disable)`, `CustomButton.disable_signal.connect(self.disable)` but I get the error: `'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'`.

Comment: Signals are *unbound* class attributes, can only be used from instances, and are unique to *that* instance. If you want to disable all instances of a widget, then make a list of those instances and connect the signals to a function that iterates them and sets the state.

Comment: Alternatively, create a separate `QObject` sub-class which defines the shared signals and set an instance of it as a class attribute. Then you can do `self.signals.disable.connect( self.disable)` and `self.signals.disable.emit()`.